# Abstract Algebra group question

Tags: finite-groups

If $G$ be a finite group of $l$ elements. Suppose that $a$ belongs to $G$, and $\mathrm{ord}(a)=k$,can $k>l$?

I think $k$ can't be bigger than $l$, because $k$ should equal $l$.

Comment: Correct. The order of an element has to divide the order of the group.

Comment: $k$ may not equal $l$, but it will divide $l$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that the cyclic subgroup $\langle a \rangle$ has cardinality $k$.